# SUM based on Project

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to establish a period of time, let's say 30 days in this case, where per ID and Project the Amount gets added during that frame.

Essentially, the start of the 30 day sum must be when the ID and Project is first seen by the start date. And then if that same ID and Project is seen again within a 30 day period, it should be added with the previous. After 30 days, another SUM() should start if the same ID and Project appear, with another 30 day SUM().

After a lot of QA and assistance, I ran into a bug which I cannot solve for - I would greatly appreciate anyone's time and help on a solution please.

The input data frame is:

```
ID  Project Amount  Start Date
2345    251 3       3/20/17
3456    251 50      4/10/17
1234    203 75      4/12/17
1234    203 100     4/13/17
2345    251 4       4/16/17
3456    251 125     4/28/17
3456    251 300     4/28/17
3456    251 50      3/22/18
3456    251 100     3/23/18
1234    203 1       5/29/18
1234    203 2       5/29/18
1234    203 29.65   5/29/18
3456    251 43.75   6/5/18
```

Expected Output:

```
ID  Project Period  Amount
1234    203 0       175
1234    203 9       32.65
2345    251 0       7
3456    251 0       475
3456    251 7       150
3456    251 9       43.75
```

Actual output:

```
ID  Project Period  Amount
1234    203 0       175
1234    203 9       32.65
2345    251 0       7
3456    251 0       50
3456    251 5       425
3456    251 7       150
3456    251 9       43.75
```

As you can see, the 425 and 50 are for some reason not being added together. The actual should display 475, coming from 50 on 4/10/17, 125 on 4/28/17, and 300 on 4/28/17.

I did attempt to also "sort_values" by Project as well, but that did not work. Again, I continue to appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: I'm confused by the 30 day thing - can you simply that? If the same ID appears again within 30 days, you want them aggregated together? is that correct?

Comment: Hi Matt! If the ID appears again and it has the same Project number as well within 30 days, they should be aggregated together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically looking at an island-and-gap problem. For rows with the same `ID` and `Project`, an "island" spans 30 days. Any row whose `Start Date` falls in this period is grouped to the same island. Otherwise, they start a new "island".

```
def summarize(x):
    date = x['Start Date'].iloc[0]
    islands = [date]
    gap = pd.Timedelta(days=30)

    for d in x['Start Date'].iloc[1:]:
        date = d if (d - date) > gap else date
        islands.append(date)

    return x.groupby(islands).agg({
        'Amount': 'sum'
    })

df.sort_values('Start Date').groupby(['ID', 'Project']).apply(summarize)
```

Output:

```
                         Amount
ID   Project                   
1234 201     2018-07-16  100.00
     203     2017-04-13  200.00
             2018-05-29   81.65
             2018-07-01  645.34
2345 203     2018-08-13   95.12
             2019-04-12   10.00
     251     2017-04-11    7.00
3456 251     2018-03-23  150.00
             2018-06-05   43.75
```

Comment: Hi Code Different! Thank you for of all of helping me through this problem. I updated my initial question with another dataset. Some how, the 30 day period is being extended. Would you be able to please take a look? Again, any help is appreciated. I do value your time!

Comment: So you define your "island" a little differently. See my updated answer

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, and thank you again. I appreciate the explanation through the "island" - it does make more sense! I'm getting a NameError, where dates is not defined, return x.groupby(dates).agg({

I did change dates to 'Start Date' but I still may be doing something wrong. Any thoughts please? Also, I no longer have to sort by Start Date, correct?

Comment: Sorry it's my typo. Should be `x.groupby(firstStartDates)`

Comment: Updated my original post to show a bug I'm running into. I attempted to sort by date and tried to ensure formatting was correct. Sorry for being repetitive, but I cannot express my continued thanks for your help.

Not sure if there is a way to edit my "island" to ensure it takes into account all scenarios.

Comment: You keeo finding bugs in my code! Thank you for your patience. I overthought the answer... a simple `for` loop does the job just fine

Comment: Thank you kindly Code Different! Your perseverance and help was greatly appreciated. I was able to check a few different data sets and found no bugs!